# Логика xml-gui-атрибутов

Tags: xml, наследование, android, gui

Казалось бы, в написании `GUI` с помощью `XML` нет ничего сложного. Ищем в [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) классы, наследуемые от View, записываем их в иерархическом порядке, и инициализируем нужные свойства, которые опять же прописаны в документации каждого класса.

Но, например, свойство `android:layout_weight` не является параметром `TextView`, однако добавляется туда, если его предком является `TextView`.

```
  <LinearLayout
      <TextView
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

**Мой вопрос**: по какому принципу происходит подобное наследование, как отличать наследуемые параметры от ненаследуемых, и существуют ли ещё какие-нибудь неочевидные моменты в  написании `GUI` с помощью `XML`?

Answer (score 2):

При добавлении вьюшки куда-нибудь из кода, вы используете специфичные для лэйаута `LayoutParams`:

```
// грубо
relativeLayout.addView(myView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(...));
```

Т.е. кроме параметров самого view вам нужно использовать еще параметры лэйаута контейнера, в который вы его добавляете. (в случае одноаргументного `addView(View view)` используются дефолтные параметры)

Парсер xml-ек при генерации байт-кода сделает то же самое: если вьюшка находится в `RelativeLayout`, в ее тэге могут быть аттрибуты для `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Если вы их там указали - он создаст `LayoutParams` с вашими атрибутами, если нет - будет использовать дефолтные.

Итак:

- Наследования никакого нет, просто логика описания лэйаутов в xml и в коде немного отличается.
- Все параметры `LayoutParams` любого `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`) в xml могут добавлятья в тэг наследника.
- Нет железного способа отличить параметры child от параметров лэйаута parent "на ходу". Но и надобности тоже нет. Параметры задокументированы ([`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)) Выбирая лэйаут, вы решаете какую-то задачу, а значит, вы знаете, какие параметры лэйаута вы хотите использовать, вряд ли вы их спутаете с параметрами вьюшки.
- Через пару месяцев работы с лэйаутами вы будете знать их наизусть :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: компоненты, такие как TexView имеют свои атрибуты + атрибуты, наследуемые от лэйаутов(менеджеров компоновки) таких как LinearLayout в которых они размещены(являются дочерними по отношению к ним)

Comment: Проверил. Атрибута `android:layout_weight` в классе [View][1] - нет.

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: опечатался, во ViewGroup ведь это контейнер.

Comment: точнее тут - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Там только `layout_weight` а нужен, `layout_width`. Но если вы расскажите, как ViewGroup.LayoutParams, который просто является внутренним классом для ViewGroup, каким-то образом влияет на классы наследуемые от View, это, безусловно, приблизит нас к разгадке.

Comment: Тю, я заработался. Вам вес нужен? Это специфичный атрибут для LinearLayout. Больше его нет нигде.

Comment: Да, специфичный для `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Вопрос в том как он попал в TextView.

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что он там есть? Все классы, которые лежат внутри контейнера просто могут использовать атрибуты этого контейнера. Так в случае с LinearLayout, так же и в случае с RelativeLayout

Comment: То есть все атрибуты, находящиеся в самом классе и в его внутренних классах, становятся доступны для использования в содержащихся им объектах?